# how to pass parameter like 'before' and 'limit' in Manatee Trello methods

Tags: trello, manatee.trello

first of all, thanks to @gregdennis. I use Manatee Trello namespace to query and get Actions from Trello board. there is a limitation to getting entities on each request (50 by default). In Online API documentation I read there are several parameters like 'limit' and 'before'. How I passing these parameters to methods in my code, my sample fetch code is here:

```
    Board board = new Board(boardId);
    var actions = board.Actions.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few extension methods on various collection types that will modify the API queries to add these parameters.

The first you're looking for is `Limit(this ReadOnlyActionCollection, int)`.  Just pass in the number of actions you want.  Valid values (per the API) are 0-1000.

The second is `Filter(this ReadOnlyActionCollection, DateTime?, DateTime?)` which will allow you to filter on `since` (start) and `before` (end). (The API docs say that `lastView` is a valid option for the `since` parameter.  This is not supported at the moment.)

**Edit**

Note that these extension methods work just like LINQ: they return a new instance of the query.  The query doesn't execute until the collection is enumerated.

**Edit 2**

To get any collection you have to have a Trello entity (board, list, card, etc.) first.  A collection is meaningless without the object which defines it.  For example, boards have lists, lists have cards, cards have checklists, and all of these have actions.

So to get a collection that consists of the 500 most recent actions for a card,

```
var card = new Card("<ID>");
var actions500 = card.Actions.Limit(500);
foreach(var action in actions500)
{
    Console.WriteLine(action);
}
```

**Edit 3**

Okay.  I see the problem.  I didn't use the `this` keyword in the `Limit()` extensions.  I'll fix that and publish an updated.

Until then, please use the method statically:

```
Collections.Limit(card.Actions, 100);
```

**Edit 4**

As of Manatee.Trello version 3.0.0, `Limit` is a property on all collections.  The default is 50 for most types.

Comment: I found this extension methods on this type: "ReadOnlyActionCollection". But how to fill a value derived from this type: 'ReadOnlyActionCollection r=;' because I fill the objects like this: 'var _actions = _board.Actions'. please write a full example

Comment: You're getting the actions correctly.  You just need to call the extension method.  Please see edit 2.  Also, please be sure you read the documentation in the [github wiki](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Trello/wiki).

Comment: I really appreciate your answers but if I could attach a picture to this reply, I would show my code screen shot in visual studio to you! I have "Filter()" extension method but there is no "Limit()" method!

Comment: Ah!  Please see edit 3.  Sorry about that.  Update pending.

Comment: thanks man! I used it in this way: `CollectionExtensions.Limit(board.Actions, 100);`

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if it resolved your issue.  Also, check out Manatee.Trello v1.14.1 for your fix.

Comment: thanks a lot. I upgraded to the last version and my problem was solved.

Comment: there is a problem @gregsdennis, I fetched cards action in this way: `var actions = myCard.actions.limit(1000)` but it returns just 11 from it! I checked with web API but it returns about 50 actions! is there any configuration over fetch Actions?!!

Comment: I got it. there are some default filters! and we I catch all actions by this method: `myCard.actions.Filter(ActionType.All).limit(1000)`